# django cms search with multiple sites?

Tags: django, search, django-cms

I've set up multiple sites within a single instance of django cms with haystack for search (with Solr). However, the search_indexes.py that I've got doesn't appear to have any effect. It's like it's just ignored and a default one is used. Why isn't my search_indexes.py taking effect?

I've got the following:

settings.py:

```
HAYSTACK_SITECONF = 'mysite.search_sites'
```

search_sites.py:

```
from cms.models import monkeypatch_reverse
import haystack

monkeypatch_reverse()
haystack.autodiscover()
```

mysite/app/search_indexes.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import string_concat, ugettext_lazy
from django.utils.html import strip_tags

from haystack import indexes, site

from cms.models.managers import PageManager
from cms.models.pagemodel import Page
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin

def page_index_factory(lang, lang_name):
    if isinstance(lang_name, basestring):
        lang_name = ugettext_lazy(lang_name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        if 'cms.middleware.multilingual.MultilingualURLMiddleware' in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
            return '/%s%s' % (lang, Page.get_absolute_url(self))
        else:
            return Page.get_absolute_url(self)

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        app_label = 'cms'
        if len(settings.LANGUAGES) > 1:
            verbose_name = string_concat(Page._meta.verbose_name, ' (', lang_name, ')')
            verbose_name_plural = string_concat(Page._meta.verbose_name_plural, ' (', lang_name, ')')
        else:
            verbose_name = Page._meta.verbose_name
            verbose_name_plural = Page._meta.verbose_name_plural

    attrs = {'__module__': Page.__module__,
             'Meta': Meta,
             'objects': PageManager(),
             'get_absolute_url': get_absolute_url}

    _PageProxy = type("Page_%s" % lang.title() , (Page,), attrs)

    _PageProxy._meta.parent_attr = 'parent'
    _PageProxy._meta.left_attr = 'lft'
    _PageProxy._meta.right_attr = 'rght'
    _PageProxy._meta.tree_id_attr = 'tree_id'

    class _PageIndex(indexes.SearchIndex):
        site_id = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr="site__id")
        language = lang
        text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=False)
        pub_date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='publication_date')
        login_required = indexes.BooleanField(model_attr='login_required')
        url = indexes.CharField(stored=True, indexed=False, model_attr='get_absolute_url')
        title = indexes.CharField(stored=True, indexed=False, model_attr='get_title')

        def prepare(self, obj):
            self.prepared_data = super(_PageIndex, self).prepare(obj)
            plugins = CMSPlugin.objects.filter(language=lang, placeholder__in=obj.placeholders.all())
            text = ''
            for plugin in plugins:
                instance, _ = plugin.get_plugin_instance()
                if hasattr(instance, 'search_fields'):
                    text += ''.join(strip_tags(getattr(instance, field, '')) for field in instance.search_fields)
                if getattr(instance, 'search_fulltext', False):
                    text += strip_tags(instance.render_plugin())
            self.prepared_data['text'] = text
            return self.prepared_data

        def index_queryset(self):
            qs = _PageProxy.objects.published().filter(title_set__language=lang).distinct()
            if 'publisher' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
                qs = qs.filter(publisher_is_draft=True)
            return qs

    return _PageProxy, _PageIndex

for lang_tuple in settings.LANGUAGES:
    lang, lang_name = lang_tuple
    site.register(*page_index_factory(lang, lang_name))
```

Comment: Could you add your solution to this as an answer rather than an edit, if that's possible? That way people can see it's been answered and it doesn't show up in the "unanswered" tab for Django questions. :)

Comment: He's probably gone and left SO a long time ago. I'm copying and pasting his solution in the answer box. I'll flag it and explain that I've copied the solution and that the question should be marked as approved.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the problem was with the search_sites.py which shouldn't use autodiscover. Instead it needs to import the search_indexes file which will register indexes for all plugins:

```
from cms.models import monkeypatch_reverse
monkeypatch_reverse()
import mysite.app.search_indexes
```

And then the following script runs the index over all sites:

```
import os
import sys

root = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')
sys.path.insert(0, root)

activate_this = os.path.join(root, 'venv/bin/activate_this.py')
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.conf import settings

from haystack.management.commands.clear_index import Command as clearCommand
from haystack.management.commands.update_index import Command as updateCommand

clear = clearCommand()
clear.handle(interactive=False)

for site in Site.objects.all():
    settings.SITE_ID = site.id
    update = updateCommand()
    update.handle()
```